# Can i create KendoUI controls in my Controller

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Can i create KendoUI ASP.NET MVC wrapper controls in my Controller class and pass them on to the views. And can i also display them there on the views.

for example:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        GridBuilder<CustomerViewModel> grid
            = new GridBuilder<CustomerViewModel>(new Grid<CustomerViewModel>(
                new ViewContext(), // <-- view is empty
                DI.Current.Resolve<IJavaScriptInitializer>(),
                DI.Current.Resolve<IUrlGenerator>(),
                DI.Current.Resolve<IGridHtmlBuilderFactory>()));

        ViewBag.g = grid;

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: That would be against the philosophy of the Model-View-Controller pattern. Why would you want to do that? Besides that, Kendo widgets  are not server side controls like MVC grid or MVCContrib grid. They heavily rely on client-side javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a method that uses the kendo gridbuilder type:

```
public static Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.GridBuilder<T> RenderGrid<T>(this HtmlHelper helper, string gridName)
        where T : YourObject
    {
        return helper.Kendo().Grid<T>().Do stuff here;
```

}

And you would call it in your razor markup:

```
@RenderGrid("GridName")
```

Comment: Thanks @kryptonkal, you are suggesting that make a helper function and pass the meta-data about column and data source to. This way i can try to generate my dynamic grids. One question related to it that i need to generate a page having toolbar, grid and tab controls. Are helper methods helpful to go this way you suggested as i have to put javascript and client-template code as well. My only intention is to generate most of the ui code for same type of data entry forms (e.g. admin site, setup forms).

Comment: I have accomplished the same scenario you are explaining. I use a tool bar and tab controls within the grid and apply my js code in external files and link accordingly. If you need additional explanation and/or code, let me know. Good luck.